# How can I validate a field to include only letters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say I have a 'city' or 'country' input field.
How can I validate this field to only include letter?

Currently I am replacing any eventual numeric character with a blank space like this:

```
def strip_numeric_characters
  self.city = self.city.gsub(/[0-9]/, "")
  self.country = self.country.gsub(/[0-9]/, "")
end
```

But it's not the right way, because if someone is inputting only numbers, I'll end up with en empty string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can validate attribute format using [`validates_format_of`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_format_of) like this:

```
validates_format_of :city, :country, :with => /^[a-z]+$/i
```

`/^[a-z]+$/i` will only allow city and country names with letters only. The following is the details of the regex.

```
^     => Start of line
[a-z] => Any single character in the range a-z
+     => One or more characters of the range
$     => End of line
i     => To make case insensitive
```

Comment: works when inputting only numbers, but still saves for mixed inputs like Netherlands2 for example

Comment: So you need only letters, no numeric value in it, right?

Comment: @BogdanPopa Can you try this: `validates_format_of :city, :with => /^[a-z]+$/i` ?

Comment: I changed your regexp with /\A[a-z]+\z/i, since I was getting a warning 'The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk' but it works. Thanks!

Comment: Appreciate the explanation. I accepted your answer.